# Is their a way to enumerate all Virtual Topics along with their logical destinations (consumer Queues) for ActiveMQ broker?

Tags: activemq-classic

Is their a way to enumerate all Virtual Topics along with their logical destinations (consumer Queues) for ActiveMQ broker?

I was planning to use Virtual Destination in my setup and I was looking for stats related to virtual destination like which all topic are Virtual Topic, what are their Consumer queues etc.

One way is to parse broker Config XML and get list of all topic and prefix and postfix for consumer queue and look into all destination for these names along with defaults.

But this way doesn't seems to be good way and might be inefficient. Are there any ActiveMQ provided statistics?

Comment: From where do you want to do this? This data is "internal business of the broker" and I guess is not accessible from a client. Given you want to write a plugin to the broker, or embed a broker in code, then there's another story.

Comment: I want to do it on broker side only.